# How to update a computed column in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2, calculated-columns

On a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance, we have a table where we would like to replace an existing column with a persisted computed column.  So far, so good.  We'd also like to allow existing queries that attempt to update this field to be "redirected" to actually update the "real" columns that are used to generate the value of the persisted computed column.

We've tried an `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger on the table, but get the error: *"...cannot be modified because it is either a computed column or is the result of a UNION operator."*

I know that you can intercept the update of a computed column that is a part of a *view* with an `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger, but apparently this technique does not work directly on a table itself.

We know we can modify the query or create a view and point the query at the view to make this work, but is there any way to accomplish the update without making these changes?

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding why you have queries that update a column that is now a computed column. If the value should be computed, the app shouldn't have allowed updates to that column previously. I don't think you will be able to intercept this to be honest.

Comment: Would it work to add the computed column as a new column instead of trying to re-direct the queries to update the "real" values?

Comment: No.  A view with an update trigger is the only way to do this without fixing the code trying to write to it.

Comment: @devlincarnate: We were trying to avoid modifications to the applications that access this table, but it sounds like what I'm attempting to do is either not possible or would require such obscure hackery that it probably isn't a good idea anyway.  So we will probably end up going with the new column approach as you suggest.  Thanks!

Comment: I assume that what you are really after is that the 'real' columns that 'cause' the computed column are represented within the table in such a way as you can create your computed column from them. I would try using the column that the app queries create and reverse the queries in the app to update the real columns from it, then create the computed column from the real columns that now contain the proper values to do that.

Comment: This is yet another reason why you should work with stored procedures and not generate the sql statements in your application. Using stored procedures allows you to encapsulate the actual data structure. From an oop point of view, you can think of tables as the private data of an object and stored procedures as methods.

Comment: @russ Yes, since it seems there's no good _in situ_ way to do this, we'll do it the right way when we actually change the application.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I fully agree!  This is a legacy application that is probably 15 years old.  Since there's no reasonable way to make the change we are interested in without application or query changes, we'll definitely lift the query into a stored procedure when we modify it.

Comment: Are you unhappy with the workflow or is there some detail about the column produced by the app that causes you to want to get rid of the app's column and create the persisted computed column?